# I'm not able to fully disable caching during development

Tags: 9

I'm currently developing a new Drupal 9 website. I build quite a few custom modules for this but for some reason the changes I make in the modules during development are not visible immediately.

I disabled caching as described in [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914).

The strange thing is that, even when I run `drush cr` the changes are not active. I also have my chrome development window open so the browser is not caching the pages either.
I have to empty cache and save the page a few times to get it to work.

What can I do to further disable caching so I don't have to empty the cache after I made a change?

Comment: `drush cr` is all you need to do from the Drupal side, if that’s not working check your browser settings, VM settings if applicable, settings for any reverse proxy you have active, that sort of thing

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I'm using `drush cr` to empty the cache and this is not working. And cache is disabled in my browser. What is VM or a Reverse Proxy?

Comment: I noticed [that post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) its missing `cache: false` under the `twig.config:` in development.services.yml

Comment: Thanks, I had a look but I do have this line of code in my development.services.yml file. So this is not the problem. But I think I fixed it.

The comment of Clive made me look a little further then I did before. And it looks like disabling the OPcache in MAMP does the trick.

Comment: The moment you add a new library definition or new file to an existing definition or new hook you need to flush cache anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The post ([Disable Drupal (>=8.0) caching during development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914)) had been updated, you may consider use the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module to **disable caches** during development.

By toggling "Enable development mode" checkbox, you can switch between Dev/Prod modes easily without editing any settings*.php and *services.yml files.